# atualizar coluna em branco com mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso de efetuar uma atualização numa tabela mas só nas colunas que estão em branco e não serão todas, apenas um número especifico.

Por exemplo, tendo esta tabela:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
id1  val1 val2 
id2  val1
id3
```

Pretendo atualizar o id1, id2, id3 em 2 colunas cada e ficaria assim:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
id1  val1 val2 val3 val4
id2  val1 val2
id3  val1 val2
```

Qual a melhor forma se é que tem alguma forma de o fazer...

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma de atualizar uma coluna em branco será permitir  **valores nulos** (NULL VALUES). Outra forma poderá também ser atualizar com uma **empty string**

```
Update TableName Set ColumnName='' where [Condtion]
```